# Why are flutes called recorders?

Tags: etymology, music

It seems that a certain type of flute (like the wooden one children are often given in school) is called "recorder". How did that happen?

Comment: Here you go http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081113181828AAGzgN2

Comment: Take a look at this resource: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=recorder

Answer (score 5):

As it's stated at *etymonline.com*:

> **recorder (n.)** — "chief legal officer of a city," early 15c., from Anglo-French recordour (early 14c.), Old French recordeor, from Medieval Latin recordator, from Latin recordari "remember" (see record (v.)). The musical instrument is attested by this name from early 15c., from record (v.) in the obsolete sense of **"practice a tune."** The name, and the thing, were rarely heard by mid-1800s, ousted by the flute, but enjoyed a revival after 1911 as an easy-to-play instrument for musical beginners.

Comment: [This reference](http://books.google.com/books?id=4vMKURSNO8AC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=recorder+etymology&source=bl&ots=ioyELVzyrs&sig=8rpXU8TiMGtWRkiJ5WKRmhsbFlg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=QSJDUcSpCIm5qQHN4IHYAQ&ved=0CGwQ6AEwCA) gives several theories.

Comment: @PeterShor Why commenting me? Write your own answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Peter was only trying to be helpful to you, the O.P., and anyone else who might be interested enough in this topic to open the question. Instead of composing a "competing" answer, he was gracious enough to enhance this one. Your response surprises me.

Comment: My reference actually concludes that your answer is the most likely etymology, so I don't see the point of writing another answer.

Comment: @PeterShor excuse me for being that rude.